# ansible write result to file not working on error when node is not reachable

Tags: ansible

As ansible's error reporting is not user friendly, I created a python wrapper which will read the output file and report properly if any error occurs.

```
- name: my play
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
      - name: my action
        shell: "<run some script>"
        register: rc
        failed_when: false
      - local_action: copy content={{ rc | to_json }} dest="result_{{ inventory_hostname }}.json"
```

Here the error reporting is fine. On success or failure, it'll dump the output of shell command to result_.json. The same I am processing with python and reporting properly when rc.rc is nonzero.

But then I wanted to modify the above to continue execution only when all nodes are reachable. So added some code at the beginning as below.

```
- name: my play
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
      - name: check if all nodes are reachable
        shell: echo ""
        register: rc
        failed_when: false
      - local_action: copy content={{ rc | to_json }} dest="result_{{ inventory_hostname }}.json"
      - name: fail here
        local_action: shell /bin/false
        when: rc.rc != 0
        
      - name: my action
        shell: "<run some script>"
        register: rc
        failed_when: false
      - local_action: copy content={{ rc | to_json }} dest="result_{{ inventory_hostname }}.json"
```

Now in this case, in the first action I'm doing a simple echo and testing whether the node is reachable or not. I was expecting, when the node is not reachable, the register will contain proper output. But the error is different and there is no result_.json file created for unreachable nodes. However the result file is created for reachable nodes where echo is succeeding. Anyhow the playbook is aborting at that position, but I'm unable to report the error properly.

```
fatal: [node-1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host <node-1 IP> port 22: Connection refused", "unreachable": true}
```

I'm not sure how to proceed with this. Even if there is any dump to result_.json file, I can proceed with python processing the file according to the result.

Any help would be appreciated. What modification can I do above to dump everything to a result file and abort if the node is not reachable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use [`ignore_unreachable`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html) on play or task (since gather_facts is false in this case) to ignore the unreachable host error. On the first task (check if all nodes are reachable), `rc.unreachable` will be `true` if the host isn't reachable.

Example use on play below.

```yaml
- name: my play
  hosts: all
  ignore_unreachable: yes
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to use the `rc.unreachable` in conjunction with whether it's defined or not. I had to do few more changes to my code though. But `ignore_unreachable: yes` is working like a charm.